# Using SP JSOM and XSS

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a custom html form to collect data to put into an SP Custom list. In the form are several text inputs. When using JSOM to add the item to the list, is there server side code to prevent XSS in the text inputs?

I do not have access to the server side to work with submitted data.

I could try some kind of client side JS escape function to try to prevent XSS before submitting but my research seems to indicate clients side validation can be usurped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint can be attacked through XSS attack. In default SharePoint configuration, SharePoint isn't vulnerable to XSS attacks, but, as it allows to insert JavaScript, it is possible to attack using an XSS attack. So, you have to be careful who you give permissions, and make some changes to avoid this type of attack.

As you cannot access to server side to work with submitted data, I would ask for to make a couple of changes in the configuration:

1. Add this line in the web.config:

[image]

2. Install [AntiXSS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXss/) nuget package

Here you have two good articles talking about XSS prevention in SharePoint:

- https://blog.compass-security.com/2017/03/sharepoint-collaboration-vs-xss/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2015/08/15/security-protecting-sharepoint-server-applications/

Comment: I will have to talk to the farm guys to see if this is an option. Because out system is validated on install, changes must be well documented and approved.